# Twisted SSE server subscribed to Redis via pubsub

Tags: python, redis, twisted, server-sent-events

I'm trying to build a server in Twisted which would let clients connect using Server Sent Events. I would like this server also to listen to Redis and if a message comes then push it to the connected SSE clients.

I have the SSE server working. I know how to subscribe to Redis. I can't figure out how to have both pieces running without blocking each other.

I'm aware of https://github.com/leporo/tornado-redis and https://github.com/fiorix/txredisapi, which were recommended in related questions. No idea how this helps :/

How to solve this? Could you help with both: conceptual tips and code snippets?

My Twisted SSE server code:

```py
# coding: utf-8
from twisted.web import server, resource
from twisted.internet import reactor


class Subscribe(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    sse_conns = set()

    def render_GET(self, request):
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream; charset=utf-8')
        request.write("")
        self.add_conn(request)
        return server.NOT_DONE_YET

    def add_conn(self, conn):
        self.sse_conns.add(conn)
        finished = conn.notifyFinish()
        finished.addBoth(self.rm_conn)

    def rm_conn(self, conn):
        self.sse_conns.remove(conn)

    def broadcast(self, event):
        for conn in self.sse_conns:
            event_line = "data: {}'\r\n'".format(event)
            conn.write(event_line + '\r\n')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sub = Subscribe()
    reactor.listenTCP(9000, server.Site(sub))
    reactor.run()
```

My Redis subscribe code:

```py
import redis


redis = redis.StrictRedis.from_url('redis://localhost:6379')


class RedisSub(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pubsub = redis.pubsub()
        self.pubsub.subscribe('foobar-channel')

    def listen(self):
        for item in self.pubsub.listen():
            print str(item)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what works for me.

I've ended up using txredis lib with a slight change to the RedisClient (added minimal subscribe capabilities).

```py
# coding: utf-8
import os
import sys
import weakref

from txredis.client import RedisClient

from twisted.web import server, resource
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol, defer
from twisted.python import log

from utils import cors, redis_conf_from_url


log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

PORT = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 9000))
REDIS_CONF = redis_conf_from_url(os.environ.get('REDISCLOUD_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379'))
REDIS_SUB_CHANNEL = 'votes'


class RedisBroadcaster(RedisClient):
    def subscribe(self, *channels):
        self._send('SUBSCRIBE', *channels)

    def handleCompleteMultiBulkData(self, reply):
        if reply[0] == u"message":
            message = reply[1:][1]
            self.sse_connector.broadcast(message)
        else:
            super(RedisClient, self).handleCompleteMultiBulkData(reply)


@defer.inlineCallbacks
def redis_sub():
    clientCreator = protocol.ClientCreator(reactor, RedisBroadcaster, password=REDIS_CONF.get('password'))
    redis = yield clientCreator.connectTCP(REDIS_CONF['host'], REDIS_CONF['port'])
    redis.subscribe(REDIS_SUB_CHANNEL)


class Subscribe(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    sse_conns = weakref.WeakSet()

    @cors
    def render_GET(self, request):
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream; charset=utf-8')
        request.write("")
        self.sse_conns.add(request)
        return server.NOT_DONE_YET

    def broadcast(self, event):
        for conn in self.sse_conns:
            event_line = "data: {}\r\n".format(event)
            conn.write(event_line + '\r\n')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sub = Subscribe()
    reactor.listenTCP(PORT, server.Site(sub))

    RedisBroadcaster.sse_connector = sub    
    reactor.callLater(0, redis_sub)

    reactor.run()
```